# Algorithm to find the seating capacity on each trip within a multi stop journey

Tags: algorithms

Imagine there's a boat with a fixed number of seats. The boat goes on a journey with n number of stops.

Here is a diagram of the journey where n = 4

[image]

The squares represent a stop. The lines represent a trip.

Trips occur from each stop to every other stop that comes after it.

People may go onboard at the start of a trip (which occupies a seat) and may leave at the end of the trip (which frees up a seat).

What would be the algorithm to find out the seats occupied in each trip?

Comment: I did not understand the question. How many seats are initially occupied? In what order does the boat choose the trip's source and destination? Could you please give reference to where you find this problem. Please tell your thoughts on the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

To find out the seats occupied in each trip, you can use the following algorithm:

**Step 1.** Initialize an empty array or list to store the seats occupied in each trip.

**Step 2.** Create a 2D array or matrix to represent the stops and trips. The rows represent the stops, and the columns represent the trips.

**Step3.** Iterate over each stop, starting from the first stop to the second-to-last stop.

**Step4.** For each stop, iterate over the trips that start from that stop and go to subsequent stops.

**Step5.** During the iteration, for each trip, determine the occupied seats.

- If the current stop is A and the subsequent stop is B, you can represent the occupied seats as a tuple (A, B, occupied_seats), where occupied_seats is a list or set of seat numbers occupied during the trip from A to B.
- To determine the occupied seats, you can use a seat allocation algorithm. One simple approach is to assign seats sequentially starting from seat 1, and if a passenger leaves the boat, mark their seat as available again.
- Keep track of the occupied seats for each trip segment.

**Step6.** After iterating over all the stops and trips, you will have a list of occupied seats for each trip segment.

**Step7.** You can then use this information to analyze the occupancy patterns or perform further calculations as needed.

Answer (score 1):

How I implemented this algorithm in go:

```go
func calcRouteTripSeating(trip Trip) error {
    // Flatten all toStops into on array
    var toStops []RouteToStop
    for i := range trip.Route.Stops {
        for j := range trip.Route.Stops[i].ToStops {
            toStops = append(toStops, trip.Route.Stops[i].ToStops[j])
        }
    }
    // Find boarding and unboarding number at each stop
    for i := range trip.Route.Stops {
        for j := range toStops {
            for k := range trip.Bookings {
                if !trip.Bookings[k].IsPaid {
                    continue
                }
                if *trip.Bookings[k].RouteToStopID == toStops[j].ID {
                    occupiesSeatCount, err := getOccupiesSeatCount(trip.Bookings[k].Customers)
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }
                    if trip.Route.Stops[i].Order == toStops[j].RouteStop.Order {
                        trip.Route.Stops[i].Boarded += occupiesSeatCount
                    } else if trip.Route.Stops[i].Order == toStops[j].Order {
                        trip.Route.Stops[i].Left += occupiesSeatCount
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Loop through all the stops
    // Find all toStops that start at a stop and end after that stop
    // Assign the current boarded value to toStop if it is greater than the
    // toStop's value
    var current int64
    for i := range trip.Route.Stops {
        current += trip.Route.Stops[i].Boarded - trip.Route.Stops[i].Left
        for j := range toStops {
            if toStops[j].RouteStop.Order <= trip.Route.Stops[i].Order && toStops[j].Order > trip.Route.Stops[i].Order {
                if current > toStops[j].Booked {
                    toStops[j].Booked = current
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Assign booked amounts back into original object
    for i := range trip.Route.Stops {
        for j := range trip.Route.Stops[i].ToStops {
            for k := range toStops {
                if toStops[k].ID == trip.Route.Stops[i].ToStops[j].ID {
                    trip.Route.Stops[i].ToStops[j].Booked = toStops[k].Booked
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```